# Matching products with optional factors with definite heads

Tags: pattern-matching

I need to match a products with exactly one factor `F`, an arbitrary number of factors of head `A`, and possibly additional inert factors.   I'm having trouble writing one pattern that can capture all the following cases.

I tried the following rule (the `c` term is there for show)

```
rule1 = Times[ayes___A, F] :> func[Times[ayes], F];

c + F             /. rule1
c + A[x] F        /. rule1
c + A[x] A[y] F   /. rule1
c + d A[x] A[y] F /. rule1
```

> ```
> c + F                        (*desired: c + func[1,F]  *)
> c + func[A[x], F]            (*correct*)
> c + func[A[x] A[y], F]       (*correct*)
> c + d func[A[x] A[y], F]     (*correct*)
> ```

The first expression failed to properly match, because it doesn't have head `Times`.  Then I tried a second rule with `Optional`:

```
rule2 = rule2 = Times[Optional[ayes__A], F] :> func[Times[ayes], F];

(*Input same as above but with /. rule2*)
```

> ```
> c + func[1,F]                (*correct*)
> c + func[A[x], F]            (*correct*)
> c + func[A[x] A[y], F]       (*correct*)
> c + d A[x] A[y] func[1, F]   (*desired: c + d func[A[x] A[y], F] *)
> ```

This time the fourth expression failed to match because of the extra factor.  So now I try a third rule to accommodate that extra factor:

```
rule3 = Times[extra_. Optional[ayes__A], F] :> extra*func[Times[ayes], F]

(*Input same as above but with /. rule3*)
```

> ```
> c + func[1,F]              (*correct*)
> c + func[A[x], F]          (*correct*)
> c + A[y] func[A[x], F]     (*desired: c + func[A[x] A[y], F]*)
> c + d A[y] func[A[x], F]   (*desired: c + d func[A[x] A[y], F] *)
> ```

Now the pattern matcher got confused probably because of all the optional arguments.

Is there a single pattern that can match all these cases?  Since I'm working with potentially large expressions, I would also prefer to avoid using pattern tests (`Conditional`) for performance reasons.

Comment: Does this get them all? `Times[a_. ayes__A, F] | a_. F :> a func[Times[ayes], F]`?

Comment: @march  It doesn't get the third expression properly,  `c + A[y] func[A[x], F]`

Comment: Right. Missed that one. I still think `Alternatives` is the way to go, although I'm not sure if it has the same performance hit as using pattern tests. For instance, `rule1 = Times[ayes__A, F] | Times[a_ ayes__A, F] | a_. F :> a func[Times[ayes], F];`.

Answer (score 2):

`ReplaceAll` can use a list of rules.

Here the first rule in the list addresses `Times` and `F`. The second rule (which is only invoked if the first rule is not used) addresses `Plus` and `F`.

```
rule = {Times[F, extra_., ayes__A] ->  extra func[Times[ayes], F],
  c_ + F -> c + func[1, F]}
```

Now

```
c + F             /. rule
c + A[x] F        /. rule
c + A[x] A[y] F   /. rule
c + d A[x] A[y] F /. rule
```

produces

```
c + func[1, F]
c + func[A[x], F]
c + A[x] func[A[y], F]
c + d func[A[x], A[y], F]
```